# Is is normal to have "Pods/Products/" files red/missing?

Tags: cocoapods

I am trying to understand CocoaPods better and if there's something wrong with my setup.

I have my `Pods/Products/` directory show it's content as red (missing) in XCode, is this an issue?

Specifically I am accessing a `Storyboards.bundle/xxx` file and when I run that code it crashes, saying it can't find the bundle. The place where I see this `Storyboards.bundle` is in the previously mentioned directory, and it's red which means its missing... is there a way for me to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is completely normal. Those frameworks are generated during build. They are red, because they are *currently* missing, but during the CocoaPods build phase they are created.

Don't worry about it, just close that group up and forget about it.

Comment: hey @squarefrog, but what if when i run archive, i get Framework not found Base64